# Не работают команды reboot, dhclient, usermod и др. в Linux Debian10 на VirtualBox

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox

Поставил на VirtualBox 6 Debian 10. Сделал apt update - все вроде прошло норм. Далее под root пытаюсь получить адрес, dns и шлюз:

```
dhclient
```

- "comand not found"
  Аналогично c командами reboot, usermod.
  Пробовал их искать через whereis - ищет.
  Не могу понять почему не работают команды?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть переменная окружения PATH (посмотреть - echo $PATH) - это путь, по которому ищутся программы. Он устанавливается в .bashrc и т.п. ifconfig по умолчанию в дебиане сейчас не ставится, вместо него ip. Вместо su root используйте "su -" — оно как раз переустанавливает переменные (точнее, работает как login shell)

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev частенько устанавливают дебиан без файла /root/.profile

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 2):

из `$ man su`:

> `-`, `-l`, `--login`
> ...
> initializes the environment variables HOME, SHELL, USER, LOGNAME, and PATH

без указания этой опции в переменной окружения `PATH` остаётся то же самое значение, которое у «обычного» пользователя не включает каталоги `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` и `/usr/local/sbin`.

а приведённые вами программы как раз и располагаются в этих каталогах.

потому либо добавляйте упомянутую опцию при выполнении программы `su`:

```
$ su -l <другие аргументы>
```

либо указывайте полный путь к программам, располагающимся в каталогах `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` и `/usr/local/sbin`:

```
# /usr/sbin/usermod <аргументы>
```

Comment: В каком файле нужно прописать полный путь к  программам, располагающимся в каталогах /sbin, /usr/sbin и /usr/local/sbin?

Comment: Где можно посмотреть как это прописывается?

Comment: ни в каком файле это не «прописывается». просто не забывайте про опцию `-l` при использовании программы `su`.

Comment: echo $PATH: /usr/local/sbin: /usr/local/bin:... - получается там пути прописаны?

Comment: -l dhclient - command not found

Comment: ls -l /root - total 0. Т.е. нет не одного файла и профиля соответственно

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать`su -l` вместо `su root`. su без названия пользователя автоматом запускает root оболочку. Для удобства добавь алиас в .bashrc:
`alias su="su -l"`.

Answer (score -1):

Дебиан не передает `*/sbin/` в `PATH` при заходе через судо или через рут.

Быстрый фикс и начинает работать

```
source /etc/profile
```

А так скопируйте

```
cp /etc/profile /root/.profile
```

Или опишите новый `/root/.profile` не забыв загрузить переменную PATH c путями `*/sbin/`